# facebook omniauth login with rails/devise not working because of error validating authentication code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, omniauth, omniauth-facebook

I am trying to allow my users to login using facebook into a rails application.  Here is the "sign up with fb link":

```
<%= link_to "Sign in with FB", omniauth_authorize_path(resource_name, provider) %>
```

That generates the following html:

```
<a href="/users/auth/facebook">Sign in with Facebook</a>
```

That should take me to this controller:

```
class Users::OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController

  before_action :test_if_in_right_controller

  def facebook
    puts "in the fb controller"
    # Attempt to find the User
    @user = User.find_for_facebook_oauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"], current_user)
    puts "1.  in fb.  user is #{@user.inspect}"
    if @user.persisted?
      puts "2. user persisted"
      sign_in_and_redirect @user, :event => :authentication # This will throw if @user is not activated
      set_flash_message(:notice, :success, :kind => "Facebook") if is_navigational_format?
    else
      puts "3.  in else statement.  user did not persist."
      #session["devise.facebook_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
      redirect_to new_user_registration_url
    end
  end

  def passthru
    puts "in the passthru"
    render :file => "#{Rails.root}/public/404.html", :status => 404, :layout => false
  end

  def test_if_in_right_controller
    puts "in the before action"
  end

end
```

**Heres the issue:**

The before_action is working because the `puts "in the before action"` line appears in the logs.  But then none of the other `puts` in the controller are working.  What's really weird is that facebook is actually being contacted because I get the following error:

```
E, [2015-11-04T08:44:36.357124 #1049] ERROR -- omniauth: (facebook) Authentication failure! invalid_credentials: OAuth2::Error, : 
{"error":{"message":"Error validating verification code. Please make sure your redirect_uri is identical to the one you used in the OAuth dialog request","type":"OAuthException","code":100,"fbtrace_id":"DAgHQ3MuN59"}}
```

**Here are the full server logs**

```
Started GET "/users/auth/facebook/callback?code=AQA-MlSTW1tu9NuiaRa73XpD2nJKOgEmdFjFq3dZMC0m48Eep04dbql-2I80Up9CBYTAD_D7NRG_sVLVjMWRlvDtWirDhZuv1XdVZQti3I-ljSYSoiXhcYsleIZnK9osNkuYAFhF40mqM44-fZAiAGME2ny2ISj0XQIw4vvJvQDUkhS1W1jssMmCJfJM1gLbsyjgz3X3kgMRMS6_i-DTreS-lQLamfL5Kv3ElUenLTlZsmNwb3aTzcFtIV6X_5-c5XrVEs-VMmNdtEPiUFccAa6aOfwzPeP_iEyWz2F38KlKgCpOVapLVzH_fjx_LN0XOTRwJxreDe66gDP1MbgRhGMiahxQaaGEDxgxDYy3bxKW-g&state=3de1318e2031f74043cb6bd387b1eda3b3ba244d749993c5" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-11-04 08:44:36 -0500
I, [2015-11-04T08:44:36.141145 #1049]  INFO -- omniauth: (facebook) Callback phase initiated.
E, [2015-11-04T08:44:36.357124 #1049] ERROR -- omniauth: (facebook) Authentication failure! invalid_credentials: OAuth2::Error, : 
{"error":{"message":"Error validating verification code. Please make sure your redirect_uri is identical to the one you used in the OAuth dialog request","type":"OAuthException","code":100,"fbtrace_id":"DAgHQ3MuN59"}}
Processing by Users::OmniauthCallbacksController#failure as HTML
  Parameters: {"code"=>"AQA-MlSTW1tu9NuiaRa73XpD2nJKOgEmdFjFq3dZMC0m48Eep04dbql-2I80Up9CBYTAD_D7NRG_sVLVjMWRlvDtWirDhZuv1XdVZQti3I-ljSYSoiXhcYsleIZnK9osNkuYAFhF40mqM44-fZAiAGME2ny2ISj0XQIw4vvJvQDUkhS1W1jssMmCJfJM1gLbsyjgz3X3kgMRMS6_i-DTreS-lQLamfL5Kv3ElUenLTlZsmNwb3aTzcFtIV6X_5-c5XrVEs-VMmNdtEPiUFccAa6aOfwzPeP_iEyWz2F38KlKgCpOVapLVzH_fjx_LN0XOTRwJxreDe66gDP1MbgRhGMiahxQaaGEDxgxDYy3bxKW-g", "state"=>"3de1318e2031f74043cb6bd387b1eda3b3ba244d749993c5"}
in the before action
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/login
Completed 302 Found in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

**Here is the `User.find_for_facebook_oauth` method in the facebook method from the controller**

```
def self.find_for_facebook_oauth(auth, signed_in_resource=nil)
  puts "in the fb model method".green
  user = User.where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first
  puts "1.  user is #{user.inspect}".green
  # The User was found in our database
  return user if user

  # Check if the User is already registered without Facebook
  user = User.where(email: auth.info.email).first
  puts "2.  user is already registered without fb.  #{user.inspect}".green
  return user if user

  # The User was not found and we need to create them
  new_user = User.create(name:     auth.extra.raw_info.name,
              provider: auth.provider,
              uid:      auth.uid,
              email:    auth.info.email,
              password: Devise.friendly_token[0,20])

  puts "the new user is #{new_user.inspect}".green
end
```

In my config/intitializers/devise.rb file, I have:

```
config.omniauth :facebook, ENV['APP_KEY'], ENV['FACEBOOK_SECRET_ID']
```

Comment: This error comes from Facebook. Are you sure host you're trying to log in from is added in Facebook app config?

Comment: Have you configured an app in facebook dev? Have you configured you APP_KEY and APP_ID in devise config? https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth:-Overview

Comment: Yes, I have this line in the devise.rb file: `config.omniauth :facebook, ENV['APP_KEY'], ENV['FACEBOOK_SECRET_ID']`

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are testing on your local computer, in the developers.facebook.com portal, in your app settings->advanced you should have a whitelist for your callback:

http://localhost:3000/users/auth/facebook/callback

[image]